# Send Jquery array value to codeigniter controller not working....

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to identify which button is press. And store the substring(service type) of id of button in database. Using jquery I got the substring of id of button. In next step I want to sent the value to controller. Using following codes I try to do it. But don't get any value inside the controller...

Jquery:

```
$('.select_service').click(
            function(){
             var service_type = this.id.substr(0,7);
                    var datas='service_type='+ service_type;
                    alert(datas);//this work fine
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",    
                        url: base_url + 'select_service',
                        data: datas,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                        //window.location.href=base_url + 'edit_profile';

                        }
                    }); 
                return false;
            }

        );
```

select_service.php view file

```
...............
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="select_service"  name="register" value="599 /-pm" id="list_pm_bt"></p>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                <p>Half Yearly:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="select_service"  name="register" value=" 3299 /- " id="list_hy_bt"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2">
                <p>Annual:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-4">
              <p class="submit"><input type="submit" class="select_service"  name="register" value=" 5999 /- " id="list_an_bt"></p>
            </div>
              </div>
..............
```

select_service.php controller

```
public function index()
    {

        $this->load->view('select_service');
        $select_service =$this->input->post('data', TRUE);
            echo "select controller";//it work
            echo $select_service;//nothing to display
        if($this->input->post('data')) 
                {
                            echo "update data";//it does not work
                $this->service($select_service);
                }
    }

    public function service($select){ 
            $select_service =$select;
            $array = array('service_type'=>$select_service);
            $result = $this->register_model->add_service($array);
            redirect(base_url().'edit_profile/');
    }.......
```

register_model.php

```
function add_service($array){
        $email=$this->session->flashdata('email');
        $this->db->select("email");
        $this->db->from("store");
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            echo $query->num_rows();
        }else{
            $store_id = $this->db->update('store',$array);
            return 1;}
```

Comment: try using var datas= {tadada: 'service_type='+ service_type}; and reference tadada as POST variable you receive.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.select_service').click(
            function(){
             var service_type = this.id.substr(0,7);
                    var datas= {tadada: 'service_type='+ service_type};
                    alert(datas);//this work fine
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",    
                        url: base_url + 'select_service',
                        data: datas,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                        //window.location.href=base_url + 'edit_profile';

                        }
                    }); 
                return false;
            }

        );
```

In php you will the tadada as POST variable

Comment: make sure that, in php, instead of $select_service =$this->input->post('data', TRUE); you use $select_service =$this->input->post('tadada', TRUE);

Comment: Hm, your code it's a bit complicated. Try with the next answer, if it's still now working check if you are sending the post to a page and it's sent successfully. Then, as you did, try to figure out how the data you receive looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Your post key is `service_type` not `data`

```
$select_service =$this->input->post('service_type', TRUE);
```

Comment: I change it.. but still not working. I think jquery part is ok.. Uncommand this line window.location.href=base_url + 'edit_profile'; then it go to new url. still some more error in recieving part..

Comment: what is the value of `base_url`

Comment: I think no error in base_url I use redirect(base_url().'edit_profile/'); inside index() function it redirect.. to edit_profile page..

Comment: Try `url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>select_service",`

Comment: I try it but still not working. I think code does not enter inside if($this->input->post('service_type')) statement...

Comment: Please see my answer there is no post key named `data`, its `service_type` `if($this->input->post('service_type')){`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47558/discussion-between-mridul-and-nouphal-m)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.select_service').click(
        function(){
         var service_type = this.id.substr(0,7);
                var datas='service_type='+ service_type;
                alert(datas);//this work fine
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",    
                    url: base_url + 'select_service',
                    data: { data: datas },
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                    //window.location.href=base_url + 'edit_profile';

                    }
                }); 
            return false;
        }

    );
```

An get the value of data in your controller with `$this->input->post('data')`